# Which authentication is better for MS-SQL Server 2019 : integrated security=SSPI vs uid=sa;pwd=xx | windows auth vs sa auth

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2019, sql-authentication

In my different web applications I use both ways, however, I would like to learn which method is better:

```
1: server=localhost;database=x; integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False; Trusted_Connection=Yes; 

2: server=localhost;database=x;uid=sa;pwd=y;
```

In my web application, for each database query, I open a connection and then close the connection.

So I am pretty much using the regular style such as:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection))
        {
            DA.Fill(dSet);
        }
    }
```

You can safely assume that there are hundreds or even thousands of queries at any given second.

My questions:

Are there any performance wise difference between 2 authentication methodology?

Are there any security difference between 2 authentication methodology?

I don't allow remote connections to the SQL Server. So only local connections are allowed.

Operating system Windows Server 2019

Comment: You mention the `sa` login in your connection. You shouldn't have the `sa` as your app user unless absolutely necessary. If your application would happen to suffer a SQL Injection attack, with `sa` credential the attacker would be able to do anything with your database and wouldn't even have the trouble of searching for the names of objects as `sa` has access to a bunch of default objects that exists in a SQL Server instance. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15#before-you-begin).

Comment: If performance is your concern, it's very likely that you could find queries on your application that would benefit of improvement before increasing the security risk by using a SQL Server login in order to make authentication faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Security Difference

You can find that on the [Connecting Through Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-through-windows-authentication) doc:

> Windows Authentication is the default authentication mode, and is much
> more secure than SQL Server Authentication. Windows Authentication
> uses Kerberos security protocol, provides password policy enforcement
> with regard to complexity validation for strong passwords, provides
> support for account lockout, and supports password expiration. A
> connection made using Windows Authentication is sometimes called a
> trusted connection, because SQL Server trusts the credentials provided
> by Windows.

### Performance Difference

The existing performance difference between these two methods isn't enough to advise you to choose SQL Server Authentication over Windows Authentication to gain any performance improvement in detriment of security. Therefore, **if you have the option to use Windows Authentication, use it.**

As [J.D.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150011/j-d)'s comment says, storing credentials is not the safest option and even the performance disadvantage of Windows authentication was mitigated with [SQL Server connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql-server-connection-pooling?view=sql-server-ver15) as mentioned by [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman). He also added:

> I tested 10K connection open/close requests in my test lab on bare
> metal. The average milliseconds per connection were: SQL auth with
> polling: 0.10838721, Windows auth with pooling: 0.12424151, SQL auth
> with no pooling: 2.66011692, Windows auth without pooling: 3.2432628.
> Consider that query execution rather than connections will likely be
> the long pole in the tent.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Even authentication protocols aside, storing credentials in the application layer is an added security risk that just doesn't exist when you use a **Trusted Connection** that passes through the authentication from Windows. This is good info from Ronaldo. Regarding performance differences, there shouldn't be any.

Comment: @J.D. and ronaldo ty for answers

Comment: There are performance differences. Windows authentication requires comminication to a domain controller, which is not needed with SQL auth. That said, the performance penalty is usually insignificant and mitigated by connection pooling.

Comment: @DanGuzman so in practice, there should not be noticeable difference. Anyone experimented on this? Because I can use either way. The server is only managed by me so there is not really any security issue.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG you shouldn't be concerned only with other admins of the server, but any malicious attacks that could come to your server or applications. As J.D. mentioned, storing credentials is not the best option and even the performance disadvantage of Windows authentication was mitigated with [SQL Server connection pooling (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql-server-connection-pooling?view=sql-server-ver15) as mentioned by Dan Guzman. Thank you guys for making it a much better answer. I'm gonna update it soon.

Comment: @DanGuzman To initially authenticate the user to establish the connection, there could be performance differences, sure. And theoretically this could go either way, but it is negligible especially in the grand scheme of things. But I took OP's question regarding performance moreso about executing queries under one connection context vs the other, which there shouldn't be any actual performance differences (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, the last paragraph of Ronaldo's answer sums it up well; use Windows auth when possible. As to performance, I suggest you [I suggest race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). FWIW, I tested 10K connection open/close requests in my test lab on bare metal. The average milliseconds per connection were: SQL auth with polling: 0.10838721, Windows auth with pooling: 0.12424151, SQL auth with no pooling: 2.66011692, Windows auth without pooling: 3.2432628. Consider that query execution rather than connections will likely be the long pole in the tent.

Comment: I'll add that I have seen significant differences in production when Windows authentication requests were inadvertently routed to a remote DR site domain controller across the country. The problem was only observed at application startup, when a problem app opened hundreds of connections at once. It was a non-issue after that due to pooling. The Windows admins ultimately fixed the problem.